# Disable iterator debugging in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've been wondering why is application I'm now fixing running so damn slow in debug mode compared to release. The ratio can be up to 600 times, where 500ms operation takes 5 minutes.

I already gave up on any profilers available for windows, they all have some property that makes them suck, be it crashing, not loading symbols... So I decided to profile *statistically*. I randomly paused the execution using the pause button. This code fragment turned out to appear most of the time when I paused:

```
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
         if (_Myproxy != 0)
                {      // adopted, remove self from list
                _Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
                while (*_Pnext != 0 && *_Pnext != this)
                       _Pnext = &(*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter;

                if (*_Pnext == 0)
                       _DEBUG_ERROR("ITERATOR LIST CORRUPTED!");
                *_Pnext = _Mynextiter;
                _Myproxy = 0;
                }
#endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
```

This is in a Visual Studio file. I tracked how `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` is defined and unveiled that setting `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` to zero would prevent `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` from being `2`.

Now I would post the code where the `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` is being set (*edit: it's file `Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\yvals.h`*), but when I go to Project properties`->`C/C++`->`Preprocesor and add `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0`, the Visual Studio goes into endless loop and I have to kill the process `devenv.exe`.

Fortunately, I had no unsaved changes (except breakpoints). Why did this happen and how to go around it? Many features can't be tested in debug mode, because it would probably take several years.

---

VS Version info:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
```

Comment: You could export breakpoints to the file from the breakpoints window. So you would not have to set them manually again and again. I was unable to reproduce this bug on the simple test project in the VS10, so it seems it either depends on your project, or your VS updates. Have you installed VS10 SP1?

Comment: @Ari0nhh It may depend on the project indeed. I'm not the author though, so I'm quite lost. I guess I would need someone to tell me what should I look for. I updated my question with visual studio version info. It does have SP1 and several updates from Microsoft Auto-Update service.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all addons / extensions?

Comment: @typ1232 Good idea, but unfortunatelly it also happens when I turn Qt and Visual Assist off.

Comment: I also tried to put `-D "_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0"` in command line settings, but that resulted in linker errors.

Comment: `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` is still the wrong macro. You should use `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` only.

Comment: Same issue though, some of the linked libraries has this set the linker will fail because if mismatch: ` mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0'` Boost is one of the problematic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This link says you should not control this macro dicrectly:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985939.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Try setting `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0`

Comment: It has same effect, VS crashed again. I'm getting real tired of setting up the breakpoints all over again!

Answer (score -1):

In your preprocessor options set `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0` in `Preprocessor Definitions`

Comment: Same effect. Big downvote because I lost my workspace and breakpoints again.

Comment: Works for me (VS2010 using `std::vector<int>`). I guess your problem is something different.

Comment: I am not the author of the project, but I suppose it must be Visual Studio thing anyway. Maybe it's not endless loop, just very long one as the project is rather huge.